# open .pkpass file from Wallet using share extension iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, ios8-share-extension

I am trying to open .pkPass file from wallet using share extension, but its not opening. Basically its returning data and I want URL. but If I try to open .pkpassfile data in PKAddPassesViewController its not open it says  Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!.

ShareViewController

```
 override func didSelectPost() {      if let item = self.extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem{
     print("Item \(item)")
     for ele in item.attachments!{
         print("item.attachments!======&gt;&gt;&gt; \(ele as! NSItemProvider)")
         let itemProvider = ele as! NSItemProvider
         print(itemProvider)
         if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("com.apple.pkpass"){
             imageType = "com.apple.pkpass"
         }
         if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("com.apple.pkpass"){
              imageType = "com.apple.pkpass"
         }
         print("imageType :  \(imageType)")

         if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(imageType){
             print("True")
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: imageType, options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) in
                print(item)
                 var imgData: Data!
                 if let url = item as? Data{
                     imgData = url
                        //try! Data(contentsOf: url)
                    self.openPass(withName: url)
                 }else {
                    print("sorry it does not work on others")
                }

             })
         }
     }

 }self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
             }
```

open PkPass file Functions

```
 func openPass(withName passData: Data?) {
var error: Error? = nil
var newPass: PKPass? = nil
do {

    newPass = try PKPass(data: passData as! Data)
} catch {
}
if error != nil {
    UIAlertView(title: "Passes error", message: error!.localizedDescription, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ooops", otherButtonTitles: "").show()
    return
}
let addController = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: newPass!)
addController!.delegate = self
present(addController!, animated: true) 
}
```

its not opening it says Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

basically I want to open .pkpass file from wallet app using share extension in my app and then user can print or share the pass using my application. I want to get url of .pkpass file then save it to userdefults, now the issue is this .pkpass file is returning data instead of url 
 so can anyone help to fix the issue or give suggestion regarding opening .pkpass file from wallet app using share extension thankx

Comment: Did you get any solution ? May be it is working older ios , any workaround ?

Comment: No, I didn't get the solution yet

Comment: @JamshedAlam Has either of you found a solution to this?